# Openerp 6.1 put product category in sale order line

Tags: odoo

I want to show the product category in the sale.order.line.tree view of a sales order with the following code which I wrote. It shows the category button under the group by button but on clicking it, I get the following error and I have don't know how to solve the bug:`assert groupby_def and groupby_def._classic_write, "Fields in 'groupby' must be regular database-persisted fields (no function or related fields), or function fields with store=True"
AssertionError: Fields in 'groupby' must be regular database-persisted fields (no function or related fields), or function fields with store=True`

Here is my code:

```
from osv import fields, osv<code>
class sales_order_line_category(osv.osv):
_name='sale.order.line'
_inherit='sale.order.line'
_columns={'categ_id': fields.related('product_id', 'categ_id', type='many2one', relation='product.categ_id'),

}
```

sales_order_line_category()

My view:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<record id="view_sale_orderlinecategory" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.line.categoryinherit</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order.line</field>
        <field name="type">tree</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_line_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="name" position="after">
                        <field name="categ_id" string="Category"/>
            </field>            
        </field>    

    </record>



    <record id="view_sale_orderlinecategory2" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.line.categoryinherit2</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order.line</field>
        <field name="type">search</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_sales_order_uninvoiced_line_filter"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

    <group expand="0" string="Group By..." >
                <filter string="Category of Product" icon="terp-stock_symbol-selection" name="Category"                     context="{'group_by':'categ_id'}"/>
            </group>


        </field> 
    </record>

     <record id="view_sale_orderlinecategory3" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.line.categoryinherit3</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order,line</field>
        <field name="type">search</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_sales_order_uninvoiced_line_filter"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">


            <field name="name" position="before">
                        <field name="categ_id" string="Category"/>
                        </field>


        </field> 
    </record>

</data>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

WOuld you please try with following code replace?

```
'categ_id': fields.related('product_id', 'categ_id', type='many2one', relation='product.category', store=True),
```

Check that your field categ_id must be appear in tree view of sale.order.line where you try to do group by categ_id

Hope this help

Comment: thanks for your help but applying your code, I now have a new error: `ProgrammingError: column sale_order_line.price_subtotal does not exist
LINE 1: ..._line."product_uom",sale_order_line."salesman_id",sale_order...`

Comment: the field categ_id does not appear in the tree view. What have I missed please?

Comment: it will not directly appear you have to put field categ_id in tree view of sale.order.line

Comment: But I had already done that with the Xpath: `xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='name']" position="after">
                        <field name="categ_id" />
            </xpath> ` or do I have to into the tree view of sale.order.line and add it instead of inheriting like it's suggested in the documentation?

Comment: you can't add into sale.order view, you have to add in sale.order.line tree, openerp does not support group by in one2many

Comment: thanks so much @user1576199 for the support but am still at loss as I still get the following error after doing what you suggested. you can see my edited view code in the question swection:`ProgrammingError: column sale_order_line.price_subtotal does not exist
LINE 1: ..._line."product_uom",sale_order_line."salesman_id",sale_order...`

Comment: The code works now with the amended code above. How do I close please?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand question how do i close please?